# Obter o maior valor de uma array em Lua

Tags: lua

Estou a utilizar código Lua e quero obter o valor maior de um array.
Exemplo:

```
tem_array = {10,2,3,20,1}
```

Utilizei este código abaixo, mas obtenho o número de elementos e não o máximo:

```
max = math.max(unpack(tem_array))
```

Comment: pra mim funcionou: http://ideone.com/ipUIuD

Comment: Você pode utilizar um algoritmo de ordenação crescente e pegar o último elemento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código postado por você funciona como o esperado.

```
tem_array = {10, 2, 3, 20, 1}
arraymax = math.max(unpack(tem_array))

print (arraymax) -- 20
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/k0X0l5)</kbd>

Um outro modo é classificar os elementos através do [`sort()`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableLibraryTutorial) para colocar os elementos em ordem crescente e pegar o último valor.

```
tem_array = {10, 2, 3, 20, 1}
table.sort(tem_array, function(a,b) return a<b end)

print (tem_array[#tem_array]) -- 20
```

Ou utilizar o comportamento padrão do `sort()`:

```
tem_array = {10, 2, 3, 20, 1}
table.sort(tem_array)

print (tem_array[#tem_array]) -- 20
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/2Fymla)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
tem_array = {10,2,3,20,1}
table.sort(tem_array, function(a,b) return a > b end)
print(tem_array[1])
```